# How do you manage to keep credentials out of publically browsable source code?

Tags: git, version-control

Let's say you want to show the source code for a settings file but don't want 3-4 lines to show up in the public source code. Do you just manually replace those variables or are there some tricks you use, like including them in yet another separate file and including that in the main conf?

Or is it more common to just not track and include that file in the repo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I tackle this problem, and I have to deal with it in nearly every project I work on, is by utilizing a pattern I picked from someone. In this pattern--which can not only be used to keep credentials from not being under version control but also to segregate environment/platform specific settings--the main settings file, which is under version control, imports a secondary settings file that is aptly called "local_settings". This "local_settings" file is not put under version control, and for each platform that the source is deployed on, a separate, specific local_settings file is created tailored to that platform only.

I will give you an example of how I commonly do this for my Django/Python projects. There is a central, per-project `settings.py` file, which is under version control, and a platform (perhaps platform is not quite the right terminology to use here) specific `local_settings.py` file. The `local_settings.py` file is imported from within the `settings.py` file, where different setting variables are defined in the following manner:

```
import local_settings

DATABASE_USER = local_settings.db_user
DATABASE_PASSWORD = local_settings.db_pass
```

And, as an example to go along with the snippet above, the `local_settings.py` file is defined thus:

```
db_user = 'user'
db_pass = 'pass'
```

I have found this pattern when dealing with the issue in question to work really well.

Comment: This seems like a pretty nice technique, I'm gonna start using this. Do you mind providing an example of the `local_settings.py` source code?

Comment: at the bottom of your Django settings.py in source control you do this: try:
    from settings_local import *
except ImportError:
    pass

Comment: Hey Spike. I am of the opinion that in the case that the `local_settings.py` file is missing, it is usually a good idea to let the exception caused from importing a missing file/module bubble up so that the person setting up the project knows exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the context, but a common solution is to have a `application.cfg.sample` that contains no sensitive information. This file is in the repository, etc. When you actually deploy the application, you copy that file to `application.cfg` and edit in the passwords, etc.

Another approach is to let the example values work for your development, but be meaningless, i.e.:

```
host: localhost
username: user
password: test
```

This might actually be a valid database account or whatever on your development workstation, but a user wouldn't assume that it is and the information is hardly sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace the variables with example ones.

```
SETTINGS = {
     username: 'test',
     password: 'mypass'
}
```

etc.

Comment: What if you have a local copy that you push to the production server? Would you push everything but the settings file(s) if you have recently made updates? Or what if you added a setting to your local repository that's necessary when you push it to the remote one?

Comment: 1) Yeah, I would. 2) Add a dummy setting for that variable too. If you find yourself adding a lot of new settings, you probably didn't design it very well.

Answer (score 1):

You could either not check the file in, if its only a valid setting for a local configuration there really is no point to include it in the public source code or do the smart thing and encrypt the information ( in the case of an asp settings file ).