# How do I keep credentials out of source control on iOS

Tags: ios, security, version-control, credentials

My iOS application needs credentials to connect to several APIs. Because the project is open source, I don't want to check the credentials into the source code repository (git).

Ultimately, I want to be able to do something like this in my application code:

```
googleMapsApiKey = [AppCredentials googleMapsApiKey];
```

Where `AppCredentials` is initialized with a configuration file not under source control.

In the past, I've been using dynamic languages like Python or Ruby and arrived at [solutions like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126552/how-do-you-manage-to-keep-credentials-out-of-publically-browsable-source-code) to keep credentials out of source control. The approach is something like this:

1. have a public API which, at run time, parses a file containing all your credentials.
2. The config file containing all the passwords is transmitted out of band (e.g. encrypted in an email).
3. distribute an example credentials file to serve as a template for other developers

However, I don't know how to apply this approach on iOS. I can't just drop a 'passwords.json' file in the source root and parse it on app initialization. I *can't* put something in the app bundle, because the bundle is also checked into version control.

Note that **this *won't* stop malicious people from extracting the credentials from the compiled app**. I'm not looking to solve that problem at the moment. With this question I'm only interested in keeping the credentials out of source code.

Comment: Why can't you do those things? Tell the SVC tool to ignore the file so it isn't included in commits.

Comment: @Wain - I can't ignore the app bundle because the bundle is used for other things (e.g. localization files which must be checked into version control). Maybe I just need a separate "Credentials.bundle" which can be ignored by source control, but included in the application when we submit to the app store.

Comment: I thought we were talking about a single configuration file, like a plist

Comment: @Wain - single file would be fine, but I thought I could only read a file from a relative path file if it were within a bundle (e.g. using something like `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jsonTest" ofType:@"txt"];` I'm new to iOS, so it's probable I'm going down a wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really an SVC question, and from that point of view you want to simply add the configuration to a single file and have that file ignored by SVC.

Generally, I would add into the 'read me' file that this configuration file needs to be created at a specified location before the project will be valid.

Then, add the file to the project and give it target membership (so it's copied into the bundle at build time). Now, in the code, you can use something like:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"accountConfig" ofType:@"plist"];
```

to get the path to the file to load.

Comment: Being completely new to iOS, I didn't understand what a bundle was. Among other things, the bundle includes a list of reference to files to be copied into the built app. I added my credentials file to the bundle, and ignored the credentials file in version control. When a collaborator clones the repository and opens the app in xcode, they see an error because the credentials file is missing. I can send them the credentials file out of band, and everyone is happy.

Comment: Small correction: The bundle is the destination that the items are copied to. The built app contains a bundle of resources. In Xcode, you have a build phase that copies resources into the bundle.